# How to fix to make it when Image is clicked, Javascript will get the Number instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

So I'm doing a project wherein I have buttons with image for each and when I click them, it will go to a blank div.span. `<button class="number"><img src="img/1.png" />1</button>` going to `<div id="numberPad"> <div id="screen"><span> </span></div>..`
The problem is my javascript, I just want when I click the image, the image will go to that div carrying the value of "1" so that when I submit it, only the number "1" will be read by the database. Everything is working if I don't have image on it, but when I tried putting an image, the submit will not click anymore. Should I need to do something in the html image or

? or I should change something in the javascript? I just wanna know how "When Image clicked, Javascript will get the Number instead" Please help, thank you!

```
var numbers     = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var screenSpans = document.querySelectorAll('#screen span');
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var currEmail = document.getElementById('currEmail').innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '');
var guess = '';
var reset;

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
reset = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < screenSpans.length; i++) {

    // Catch if they have not entered enough digits
    if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML == ''){
        errorModal.className = 'modal';
        setTimeout(function(){
            errorModal.className = 'modal hide';
        }, 4000);

    } else {
        guess = guess+screenSpans[i].innerHTML;
        if (guess.length >= 6 && guess.length <= 12){
            $.ajax({
                  url: "submit.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data: { guess: guess, email: currEmail }
            });

            lastModal.className = 'modal';
            main.className = 'hide';
        }
    }
};
guess = '';
});

for (var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
numbers[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    reset = 0;
    nextSpan(this.innerHTML);
});
};

function nextSpan (currNumber){
for (var i = 0; i < screenSpans.length; i++) {
    if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML == '' && reset == 0){
        screenSpans[i].innerHTML = currNumber;
        reset = 1;
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Try using closure within `for` loop to surround asynchronous `javascript` or substitute `Promise.all()`, `.map()` for `for` loop.

Comment: hi sir/maam, may I know in which loop?

Comment: What is purpose of `for` loop within `submit` handler?

Comment: for the button "submit" with error modal and ajax submit.php

Comment: Are there more than one `#screen span` elements? Where is `currEmail` defined? If there are more than one `#screen span` elements, why do you need to make more than one `$.ajax()` request passing same `data` object?

Comment: yes, there are 6 span under #screen in the html. I just forgot to put here the currEmail but I have it with me. Because in the beginning of my project, I will ask the user about their personal details right away and it will be redirected to the database right away before they proceed to the numberPad div. and then after they finish clicking on the numberPad div and clicking submit, the submit has the Update sql to update the specific column they just did in the numberPad prior to their session ID during their visit in this site. Everything are fine though..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131757/discussion-between-guest271314-and-jaze).